# How to use pointers with strings?

Tags: c++

I know my question is not specific but let me explain it this code

```
char name[5][30];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    cin >> name[i];

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    cout<<name[i];
```

in the example above i created an array of characters where you can input five words each with 30 bit length. and it works just fine but when i try to use a pointer like so when you don't know how many words you are about to input. I get an error in line 5 saying a value of type int cant be asigned to char and i understand the error but how how to get pass this problem?

```
int n;
cout << "Number of names" << endl;
cin >> n;
int *name;
name = new char[n][30];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    cin >> *name;
    name++;

}

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    cout << *name;
    name++;
}
```

Comment: How exactly do you expect an uninitialized `name` to automatically point to your `new`-ed array?

Comment: `std::vector<int>` and `std::string`.

Comment: I fixed the mistake but the problem is still there. it was a typo

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't want to use [`std::vector`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Vector.html) (variable-length array) and [`std::string`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/basic_string.html)?

Comment: @GillBates can you please explain what does that do ?

Comment: Why is `name` an `int*` in the second example?  IIn what way does it make sense for a name to be an `int`?

Comment: @MikeCAT I dont know anything about vectors. im still new to c++

Comment: You need to rewind the pointer before print it. :)

Comment: @NathanOliver thank you for observing that it was a typo as well. it doesnt solve the problem

Comment: By asking that question, MikeCat is giving you a little hint - learn about `std::vector` and `std::string`, and you'll (almost certainly) have a much better solution to your problem than what you are attempting.

Comment: _"I know my question is not specific but"_ Stop right there son

Comment: @BLUEPIXY how exactly do i do that?

Comment: i will certainly learn about that @Peter

Comment: As a C++ novice you should learn about `std::vector` and `std::string` first, and about pointers and `new` forty seventh.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion @n.m.

Comment: [like this](http://ideone.com/c1FfgK)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY got it, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Use `char`, not `int`.
- Incrementing `name` doesn't seem good idea because it have to be returned to the first element before printing. I used array indexing operator.
- I guess `n` input & output should be done instead of fixed `5` input & output.

```
    int n;
    cout << "Number of names" << endl;
    cin >> n;
    char (*name)[30];
    name = new char[n][30];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cin >> name[i];

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cout << name[i];
    }
    delete[] name;
```

Comment: you didn't free memory

Comment: @Raindrop7 What I posted is not all of the program. I didn't, but it may be freed later.

Comment: @MikeCAT: I know that. but the op may continue using it unknowing the potential danger of memory leak